# What kind of control is it? In Windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, controls

Can somebody tell name of this control? Is it GridView with custom Scroll or 2D Carousel or FlipView?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be simply implemented using a GridView. The DataTemplate for it is relatively simple. A StackPanel wth vertical orientation, an Image, and some TextBlocks (and a custom control for the star rating).

Comment: What about scrolling? It is not same with default GridView scrolling, it same with FlipView, but scrolls 3 items at time

Comment: You need to set the GridView's ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode to enabled as well as the ItemsPanel's WrapGrid Orientation to Horizontal

Answer (score 0):

It's just HTML. It could be rendered using ASP.NET WebForms - possibly with a data bound control e.g. an asp:repeater might do the trick. Equally it could be constructed as HTML from the ground in code possibly using helpers. (There equally could be an asp.net control that does this out the box?)

Comment: But it is not web app, it is Official Windows Store Application.